# Why this code of python to create list and add items don't work?

Tags: python

Why this code don't work in Python if it is very simple?

```
def empty_list():return list()
def text_to_list(the_text):
    empty_list=empty_list()
    empty_list[:0]=the_text
    return empty_list
print(text_to_list("ABCD"))
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/Programming/Python/Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(text_to_list("ABCD"))
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/Programming/Python/Test.py", line 3, in text_to_list
    empty_list=empty_list()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'empty_list' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you plz explain what are you trying to do and what output do you want.

Comment: Do you wish to convert all the alphabets of string to elements of list Like ['A','B','C','D'] or you just want a list of the string ABCD like [ABCD]

Comment: It won't let me print an empty list too. Why?

Comment: I just want work with empty lists, how can I do this?

Comment: If that is all you want, then `print(list())`, or if you want the output as you've tried, then `print(["ABCD"])`

Comment: `empty_list = empty_list()` you're redefining the def `empty_list` to a variable `empty_list`. Just call it something different

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def empty_list():
    return list()

def text_to_list(the_text):
    lst = empty_list()
    return lst(the_text)

text_to_list("ABCD")
```

Your mistake is that you defined the variable and the function with the same name.

Comment: Or just `return list(the_text)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `empty_list` as a name for both your local variable and the function, so when you do this:

```
empty_list = empty_list()
```

the `empty_list()` function is shadowed by the local variable and the interpreter assumes that the right part of the assignment is referring to the newly declared variable, thus making it referenced *during* the assignment (*before* the assignment is completed).

Just use different names for variables and functions.

Also, out of curiosity, why are you defining a function that creates an empty list instead of using `list()` directly, or even `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. You could just do this:

```
print(list('ABCD'))
```

instead of this:

```
def empty_list():
    return list()

def text_to_list(the_text):
    empty_list_new = empty_list()
    empty_list_new[:0] = the_text
    return empty_list_new
```